# How to Insert Values From Column A to Column B From Two Different Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL Oracle, I want to insert in my column A (from table T1) values from column B (from table T2)

I've got the following request :

```
INSERT INTO schema.T1(A)
        SELECT B FROM schema.T2;
```

And I've got the following error :

> ORA-00904 "B" invalid indentifier

When I check what's in the Table T2 :

```
SELECT * FROM schema.T2
```

I can clearly see that there's a B column with values...

I've already checked if :

- the data types are the same
- the data can be null
- there's no constraints exceptions

So when I launch this, for example :

```
SELECT * FROM schema.t2 WHERE column1=1
```

or even

```
SELECT column1 FROM schema.t2
```

It works, but when I do this :

```
SELECT B FROM schema.t2
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM schema.t2 WHERE B = ...
```

It doesn't work, and it's the same for all the columns in table T2 except the first one..

Thanks for your time to help

### EDIT

If you add trigger on those columns that need the double quote, it won't work (it didn't worked for me). The column isn't recognized and the trigger will drop an error. I'll go further on my research to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have column represented by B in table T2? Looks to me like mispelling.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure, I've already test with other column and tables, but I still have this error. I've already test for constraint, not null,... exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution.. It's really simple but I didn't know the trick.

When you have this kind of error, it can be resolved by adding double quote on the column name. The column name needs to be in only alphanumeric characters and special characters $, _.

If it contains other characters, it must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

So it looks like this :

`INSERT INTO schema.T1(A)
        SELECT "B" FROM schema.T2;`

And then it works perfectly !

Thanks for your help !!! :-)

Answer (score -1):

B does not exist in T2. You will either need to create it or find out which column corresponds in reality to the B you expected.

Comment: It's a bit tricky cause I can see the B column, and there's data in it. But it seems that it can't recognize it...

Comment: @LPK can you show me a screenshot? I think the B you want to use differs from the B which exists in a character or so.

Comment: @LPK I would need further information about t2.B to give you any further help.